# Can I relocate bird's nest?

Tags: ornithology

Doing a deck project and found a bird's nest.  Can I safely move it in order to continue working?

[image]

Think they'll fledge soon?
This is in New Jersey.

Answer (score 3):

You can move it but the parents will likely not return to it or care for the chicks.  If they are nearly ready to leave the nest, perhaps you might wait a bit until that happens.

I'd say put things back the way they were and keep an eye on the nest.  If the parents don't return there is nothing more you can do.

Comment: I think they will be gone in not much longer than one week.

Answer (score 0):

This same thing happened to us only we found eggs and not birds. We decided to leave it and wait for the birds to do their thing.

It doesn't look like you would have to wait too long on that one but probably not what you were hoping for.

Comment: Welcome to Biology.SE! While anecdotes are potentially interesting, answers are much more likely to receive a favorable response if they include supporting references (primary literature is best). Without that support, your answer is indistinguishable from opinion and would be more appropriate as a comment. ——— Please take the [tour] and then consult the help pages for additional advice on [Answer] effectively on this site and then [edit] your answer accordingly. Thanks! 